# NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Could not find the requested application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

`Xamarin.UITest` gives an error:

> "NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Could not find the requested
>   application."

I tried with the released app version with the distributable provisioning profile. 
Can't we test the release version app using `xamarin.uitest`?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, No.

You can not normally use UITest on the iOS release builds as it does not include the UITest agent (it is normally #if/#end out of release configurations).

Test frameworks like UITest/Calabash use a http-based driver that has to be included in the actual app in order to drive it, on the other hand frameworks like Appium use a driver that is external to the application being tested. (Appium directly uses the iOS `XCUITest` test framework for all iOS testing, Calabash, and UITest, uses a hybrid-approach, XCUITest-based and some custom via the bound HTTP driver)